# Simultaneously loop over lines in a file and files in a directory in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, file, loops

I have files in a directory and a file with information about each of the files in that directory. While looping over the files, I need the information about the file that I'm currently handling. The information in the file is listed in the same order as the files themselves.

I can't do this in Python or other languages because I can't assume these are installed on the target machine. I have Bash version 3.2. I know that it is possible with Bash version 4 using associative arrays but I don't have the guarantee that this version is installed.

Currently, I have this to read the file line by line:

```
#FILE is the path to the informations file
while read line
do
    #do something with $line
done < $FILE
```

And I have this to loop over the files in the directory:

```
for instance in "/path/to/files"/*
do
    #do something with $instance
done
```

How can I do these iterations simultaneously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `while` to read the file, just read one line inside the `for` loop.

```
for instance in "/path/to/files"/*
do
    read line
    # do something with $line and $instance
done < "$FILE"
```